# Color in custom MaterialEntryRenderer

Tags: xamarin.forms

Why this line 
`Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);`
is working in a custom **EntryRenderer** in Android (xamarin forms) and not in a custom **MaterialEntryRenderer**?

 I want to change only the underline color of the entry in material and not the underline color and the placeholder text color too.

**xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Genesys.App.Views.ConfigurationView"           
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:Genesys.App.CustomControls"
             Title="Ingrese Configuración" 
             Visual="Material">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     Padding="15" 
                     Background="white">           

            <local1:MyEntry x:Name="txtServicio" 
                   Placeholder="SERVICIO" 
                   BackgroundColor="White">         
            </local1:MyEntry>   
            
            <Button Padding="5"                    
                    Margin="5"
                    Text="guardar"               
                    TextTransform="Uppercase" 
                    TextColor="white" 
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource colorPrimary}" 
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"></Button>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>



 //class MyEntry 
  public class MyEntry : Entry
    {
    }
```

**CustomEntryRenderer in android**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace Genesys.App.Droid
{
    public class MyRenderer : EntryRenderer//this works
    {
        public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }        

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {               

                this.EditText.FocusChange += (sender, ee) => {
                    bool hasFocus = ee.HasFocus;
                    if (hasFocus)
                    {                     
                        Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Green); //changes color                    
                    }
                    else
                    {                      
                        Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);   //changes color                   
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

//don't work

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace Genesys.App.Droid
{
    public class MyRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer//don't work
    {
        public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }        

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {               

                this.EditText.FocusChange += (sender, ee) => {
                    bool hasFocus = ee.HasFocus;
                    if (hasFocus)
                    {                     
                        Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);//doesn't change color                     
                    }
                    else
                    {                      
                        Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Red); //doesn't change color                                           
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cfun Hi, updated

Comment: I find `PlaceholderColor` is the underline color for `MaterialEntry`, can not find way to change outline color in `MaterialEntryRender` by custom render, but you can create custom MaterialEntry to achieve this effect.